# What is the best way to lock down a terminal services user (via RDP) on 2008 Server

Tags: windows-terminal-services

I want my RDP users into Terminal Services to be able to open only one specific program for now and that's it.  I don't want them going to Control Panel, Other program etc.  What is the best way to do this?  I have looked into the LGPE for Software Restriction Policies but that doesn't seem to be that great. Any thoughts?  Also, we don't have active directory, it's not a domain of any kind, it's just a stand-alone 2008 Std Win Server.

Answer (score 2):

[Software Restriction Policies](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd349795%28WS.10%29.aspx) - More info in that link, links at the bottom for help getting started.